# BPMN diagram is not expanding with div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bpmn.io

I am facing one issue, while opening the bpmn diagram on a resizable & draggable modal popup. I am using the bpmn.io js library to load the diagram. I need to resize the diagram when I resize the modal popup.

[image: When modal popup open this diagram loaded]

But when I expand/resize the modal popup, the div expands but the bpmn diagram does not

[image: After expanding the modal popup]

The diagram loaded in a convas and rendered as an .svg

[image]

Can anyone help me to figure out that how to expand the bpmn diagram dynamically. The below library I am using

[bpmn.io](https://demo.bpmn.io/new)

Comment: It looks like the element containing the diagram is expanding as expected, according to your screenshots (thanks for that).  Do you mean that you want the diagram to *stretch* wider, or occupy more horizontal space?

Comment: @Neek if you check the first image, in that I haven't expand the div. In second image, I stretch (expand) the div wider but the bpmn diagram still remain with same size. It does not expand(stretch) with the div.